# Is there any way to organize attachments?

Tags: trello-cards, attachment

Is there any way to organize attachments in cards? I got a lot of attachments in my project cards and I would like to organize them in some kind of folder or groups.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not, attached files are simply listed with additional files being hidden once the list grows above 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

The best would be for you to organize the attachments to multiple cards, classifying them as needed. I often use some kind of hierarchy between cards, allowing to further organize them and whatever is inside.