# Reorder Attachments in Trello

Tags: trello

By default, Trello adds the newest attachment to the top of a stack. Short of deleting all attachments on a card and re-adding them in the order I require, is there any other way to sort them?

Comment: I have just attempted to re-order attachments on one of my trello boards, and based on that, and looking at a previous discussion it would seem not.

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39569/is-there-any-way-to-organize-attachments